# How to delete text messages in an image-only channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a discord bot called YES, and I have a text channel for images only, and I am trying to make it that if there is a text message the bot will delete it and reply "You cannot send text messages". I also made a whitelist for the bot because I want him to be able to send text messages.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    var usernames = ["YES"]
    if (usernames.includes(message.author.username)) {
        if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
            message.delete();
            client.channels.cache.get("841260660960395287").send(message.author.username + ", you cannot send text")
        }
    }
})
```

This doesn't work at all and it doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **if statement** `if (message.attachments.size > 0)` is checking, if the **attachments collection**'s size is **bigger than** 0. So it will only execute the code in it, if the **message** has **at least** one attachment.

You can apply this:

```js
if (message.attachments.size)
```

If the message has **no attachments**, the collection "attachments" should be empty, and in this case, you want to delete this message.¹

#### Also

You should [`await`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) the [`<message>.delete()>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) function, since it returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
await message.delete();
// Further code
```

OR²

```js
message.delete()
   .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username}`))
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

#### Nice to know:

You don't have to use all the '+' if you want to use variables inside a string. A simpler and way faster solution would be replacing `'` with `` ` `` and then wrap your **variable** in `${}`. In your code it would look like this:

```js
client.channels.cache.get("841260660960395287").send(`${message.author.username}, you cannot send text`)
```

---

Your fixed code should now look like this:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    var usernames = ['YES'];
    if (usernames.includes(message.author.username)) {
        if (message.attachments.size) {
            await message.delete();
            client.channels.cache.get('841260660960395287').send(`${message.author.username}, you cannot send text`);
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### References

- ¹[Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)
- ²[`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: @Uriyah Liberman If this solved your problem, I'd be happy if you mark this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with your if statement logic. It's checking if the message has more than one attachment, then deletes it. That's the issue, so by checking if the size of the collection is 0 (`=== 0`), your program will run successfully.

Comment: this didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I wasn't writing my own answer correctly, I've fixed it.